# How to generate Java code whilst navigating to webpages in browser

Tags: java, browser, automation, code-generation

Is there a way to generate Java code whilst navigating to webpages in browsers such as Firefox or IE?

I am looking for a tool or browser plugin that records the actions I make and generates code to mimic them in real time.

Comment: What java code are you referring to? As in, you navigate through your browser and there is some tool or software which generates code to mimic your navigation in real time?

Comment: Do you want the browser to generate Java code as a result of what you're doing? If so, you could write a [Firefox extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons) or something. Alternatively, do you want to use a browser [tag:automation] tool (such as [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/)) to generate Java code? As things are, it's difficult to understand what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, When i navigating in browser tool/browser plugin which generate code to mimic the navigation in real time

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to use [Selenium IDE](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp), a Firefox plugin which allows you to record your actions so that they can be "replayed" by Selenium. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990922/how-to-generate-source-code-for-selenium-in-java-which-is-by-default-html) may also be relevant.

Answer (score -1):

You mean view the Javascript (as distinct from Java)? Right click and "view source." Or you can use the built-in developer tools or, as I use, Mozilla's Firebug. In Firebug, click on "Script" to view each page of code.

Comment: My ask is to generate a java code which can navigate to the webpage while running it and it should be generate with the help of tools/browser plugin while i am manually navigating